# Material UI Autocomplete component won't clear input when Informed state is reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Material UI version 4 (the latest), and the [Informed form library](https://github.com/joepuzzo/informed).  I have a custom component (custom to integrate with Informed) that wraps the Material UI TextField which I'm rendering using the Autocomplete component.

**App component**

```js
    <Form getApi={(api) => setFormApi(api)}>
      {formApi && (
        <>
          <label>
            First name:
            <Autocomplete
              freeSolo
              options={autoOptions}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <CustomTextField field="name" {...params} />
              )}
            />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => formApi.reset()}>
            Reset
          </button>
          <FormState />
        </>
      )}
    </Form>
```

### The issue

When the reset button is clicked you can see the Informed "form state" is cleared, but the input still has a value. Any ideas on how to solve this?

### [Example - Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-lake-eekxq?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inputProps` are getting overriden by the ones provided by `Autocomplete` component, change the order you pass `...rest` props and included the `...rest.inputProps` in your custom `inputProps` with the correct value

```js
      <TextField
        {...rest} // should go first to allow overriding
        // only add value props for select fields
        // value={value}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setValue(event.target.value);
          if (onChange) {
            onChange(event);
          }
        }}
        onBlur={(event) => {
          setTouched(true);
          if (onBlur) {
            onBlur(event);
          }
        }}
        error={!!error}
        helperText={error ? error : helperText ? helperText : false}
        variant="outlined"
        margin="none"
        fullWidth
        inputProps={{
          ...rest.inputProps, // must include otherwise it breaks
          value:
            !select && !maskedValue && maskedValue !== 0 ? "" : maskedValue,
          maxLength: maxLength || undefined
        }}
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        InputProps={{
          style: sensitive && {
            color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            caretColor: "#000"
          },
          startAdornment
        }}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
        autoComplete="off"
        disabled={disabled}
      />
```

Comment: Moving `{...rest}` to the top breaks the autocomplete, any suggestions?

Comment: Ahh, I had spread `...rest.InputProps` into `InputProps` also.